# Send text field value to ruby hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have simple text field if RoR 3.2 app. Each time when user enter a new value in this text field I want to save it in ruby hash or array. Is it possible in rails?

Comment: you've mixed up everything :) So what's the question, you need to save the value server-side with Ruby? then you'll need an AJAX call. If you need to save it client-side, than why use ruby for that?

Comment: how about using cookies?

Comment: i need to save input value on server side

Comment: I think you want to save it in database, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a value inside a particular hash. See for example http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters

From the example on the page:

```
<form action="/clients" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="client[name]" value="Acme" />
  <input type="text" name="client[phone]" value="12345" />
  <input type="text" name="client[address][postcode]" value="12345" />
  <input type="text" name="client[address][city]" value="Carrot City" />
</form>
```

The value of `params[:client]` when this form is submitted will be `{:name => "Acme", :phone => "12345", :address => {:postcode => "12345", :city => "Carrot City"}}`.